# The second navigation bar disappear after one page scroll

Tags: html, css, navbar, sticky

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

.upnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #99CBFF;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
}

.logo img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 2em;
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
}

.lenteSearch button {
    float: right;
    border: 1.5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left: white;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    width: 3.5%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
}

.lenteSearch img {
    width: 90%;
}


.parolaLogin {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.parolaLogin a:link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.parolaLogin a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ricerca input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1.5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    min-height: 40px;
}


.topnav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #99CBFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
}

div.topnav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}

.topnav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}

.topnav a.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}

.topnav active {
    /* sottolineatura per le varie pagine */
    color: blue
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/StileNav.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div class="upnav">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="capoHome.php"><img src="../IMG/Logo.png" alt="Veneto in mostra"></a>
        </div>



        <form class="ricerca" action="ricerca.php" method="post">

            <div class="lenteSearch">
                <button type="submit"><img class="lente" src="../IMG/lente.png"></button>
            </div>

            <input type="text" placeholder=" Cerca..." name="cerca">

        </form>

        <div class="parolaLogin">
            $ACCEDI$<a href="../PHP/datiUtente.php">$UTENTE$</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../HTML/nuoviArticoli.html">$NUOVIARTICOLI$</a>
        </div>



    </div>

<div class="topnav">
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?pagina=$CITTA$">HOME CITTA</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=eventi">EVENTI</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=teatro">TEATRO</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=cucina">CUCINA</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=novit&aacute">NOVIT&Aacute;</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=arte">ARTE</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=attrazioni">ATTRAZIONI</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=biglietti">BIGLIETTI</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=contatti">CONTATTI</a>
    </div>
    
    <p>some random text some random text <br>some random text some random <br>text some random textsome <br>random textsome random textsome <br>random textsome random textsome <br>random textsome random <br>textsome random textsome <br>random textsome <br>random textsome <br>random textsome random textsome random textsome <br>random vtextsome random textsome random textsome random textsome vrandom textsome <br>random textsome random textsome random textsome <br>random textsome random <br>textsome <br>random textsome random textsome vrandom <br>textsome random textsome <br>random textsome random textsome <br>random textsome random<br> textsome random text some random text</p>


</body>

</html>
```

I have 2 navigation bar and I want that the first one disappear when I scroll down and the second one stay fixed on top. But it works until I scroll "one page" and then the second navigation bar also disappear. Which is the problem?

This is my code (The 2 navigation bar are in 2 different HTML file):

First Navbar:

```
<html>

<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/StileNav.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?pagina=$CITTA$">HOME CITTA</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=eventi">EVENTI</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=teatro">TEATRO</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=cucina">CUCINA</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=novit&aacute">NOVIT&Aacute;</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=arte">ARTE</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=attrazioni">ATTRAZIONI</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=biglietti">BIGLIETTI</a>
        <a href="../PHP/capoHome.php?sez=contatti">CONTATTI</a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Second Navbar:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/StileNav.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div class="upnav">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="capoHome.php"><img src="../IMG/Logo.png" alt="Veneto in mostra"></a>
        </div>



        <form class="ricerca" action="ricerca.php" method="post">

            <div class="lenteSearch">
                <button type="submit"><img class="lente" src="../IMG/lente.png"></button>
            </div>

            <input type="text" placeholder=" Cerca..." name="cerca">

        </form>

        <div class="parolaLogin">
            $ACCEDI$<a href="../PHP/datiUtente.php">$UTENTE$</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../HTML/nuoviArticoli.html">$NUOVIARTICOLI$</a>
        </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

.upnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #99CBFF;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
}

.logo img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 2em;
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
}

.lenteSearch button {
    float: right;
    border: 1.5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left: white;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    width: 3.5%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
}

.lenteSearch img {
    width: 90%;
}


.parolaLogin {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.parolaLogin a:link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.parolaLogin a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ricerca input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1.5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    min-height: 40px;
}


.topnav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #99CBFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
}

div.topnav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}

.topnav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}

.topnav a.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}

.topnav active {
    /* sottolineatura per le varie pagine */
    color: blue
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you please create a snippet?, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: @jaydeeppatel Done

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the parent file? The code where you are placing the navigation bars

Comment: @Jackson I don't know how to do it because I should pass you PHP and database

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. Looking at your code snippet demonstration it is working as you expect. The first bar (logo and search) is hidden when you scroll. The navigation bar remains visible at the top

Comment: @Jackson Yes. In my project works too, but when I scroll at the end of the "first page" of scroll it disappear. I give an example to explain myself better: the screen is 1600px (width) x 900px (height). The page has 3000px of height. When I scroll and I arrive at the 900th pixel the navbar disappear